# Solve memory issue with migrating a big bunch of data

Tags: ios, swift, memory, realm

In my previous version of my app I stored all user data into .dat files (with NSKeyedArchiver), but in my new version I want to upgrade to a real(m) database.

I'm trying to import all of this data (and that can be a LOT) into Realm. But it's taking so much memory that the debugger eventually kill my app before the migration has finished. The 'strange' thing is that the data on hard disk is only 1.5 mb big, but it's taking memory for more than 1gb so I'm doing something wrong.

I also tried to work with multiple threads, but that didn't help. Well it speeded up the migration process (which is good), but it also took the same amount of memory.

Who can help me out? See my code below for more information..

*FYI Async can be found here https://github.com/duemunk/Async*

```
import Async

let startDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1388534400).startOfDay // Start from 2014 jan 1st
let endDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(172800).startOfDay // 2 days = 3600 * 24 * 2 = 172.800

var pathDate = startDate
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let group = AsyncGroup()
var allPaths = [(Int, Int)]()

while calendar.compareDate(pathDate, toDate: endDate, toUnitGranularity: .Month) != .OrderedDescending {

    // Components
    let currentMonth = calendar.component(.Month, fromDate: pathDate)
    let currentYear = calendar.component(.Year, fromDate: pathDate)
    allPaths.append((currentYear, currentMonth))

    // Advance by one month
    pathDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: 1, toDate: pathDate, options: [])!
}

for path in allPaths {
    group.background {

        // Prepare path
        let currentYear = path.0
        let currentMonth = path.1
        let path = (Path.Documents as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("Stats_\(currentMonth)_\(currentYear).dat")
        print(path)

        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) {
            NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(_OldStatisticsDataModel.self, forClassName: "StatisticsDataModel")

            if let statistics = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? [_OldStatisticsDataModel] {
                // Loop through days
                for i in 1...31 {
                    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
                    dateComponents.year = currentYear
                    dateComponents.month = currentMonth
                    dateComponents.day = i
                    dateComponents.hour = 0
                    dateComponents.minute = 0

                    // Create date from components
                    let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar() // user calendar

                    guard let date = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents) else {
                        continue
                    }

                    // Search for order items
                    let filtered = statistics.filter {
                        if let date = $0.date {
                            let dateSince1970 = date.timeIntervalSince1970
                            return date.startOfDay.timeIntervalSince1970 <= dateSince1970 && date.endOfDay.timeIntervalSince1970 >= dateSince1970
                        }

                        return false
                    }

                    if filtered.isEmpty == false {
                        // Create order
                        let transaction = Transaction()
                        transaction.employee = Account.API().administratorEmployee()

                        let order = Order()
                        order.status = PayableStatus.Paid
                        order.createdDate = date.timeIntervalSince1970
                        order.paidDate = date.timeIntervalSince1970

                        // Loop through all found items
                        for item in filtered {
                            // Values
                            let price = (item.price?.doubleValue ?? 0.0) * 100.0
                            let tax = (item.tax?.doubleValue ?? 0.0) * 100.0

                            // Update transaction
                            transaction.amount += Int(price)

                            // Prepare order item
                            let orderItem = OrderItemm()
                            orderItem.amount = item.amount
                            orderItem.price = Int(price)
                            orderItem.taxPercentage = Int(tax)
                            orderItem.name = item.name ?? ""
                            orderItem.product = Product.API().productForName(orderItem.name, price: orderItem.price, tax: orderItem.taxPercentage)

                            // Add order item to order
                            order.orderItems.append(orderItem)
                        }

                        if order.orderItems.isEmpty == false {
                            print("\(date): \(order.orderItems.count) order items")

                            // Set transaction for order
                            order.transactions.append(transaction)

                            // Save the order
                            Order.API().saveOrders([order])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

group.wait()
```

Comment: You're allocating a large number of objects in a loop. I'd suggesting wrapping the body of your inner loops with an [autorelease pool](http://en.swifter.tips/autoreleasepool/) to limit the lifetime of the objects you're allocating within the loop. I don't know if that'll completely address your problem, but it should help!

Comment: I don't even see the Realm-specific code here. Where is the transaction opened, where is the Realm instance opened, where is it wrapped in `autoreleasepool {}`?

Comment: @bdash thanks, I will take a look into that. Have no expericence with autoreleasepool yet.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Well, I'm not stating that Realm is the problem, but I just described what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you have any luck with autorelease pools?

Comment: @bdash nope, tried it but doesn't have any affect. I read somewhere that an autoreleasepool in swift doesn't have a lot of impact. Maybe I should instead do that part in Objc.

Comment: I'd suggest using [Instruments to understand what is using the memory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/CommonMemoryProblems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH91-SW1), and working from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments of my question was suggested by @bdash, autoreleasepool did the trick.

I use AsyncSwift as syntactic sugar for grand central dispatch, but when using block groups the group keeps a reference to the block which caused that the memory wasn't released. I still make use of a group now but I leave the group after it's finished.

I provided my code example below, to make things clearer. Using multiple threads gave me incredibly (like 10 times faster) more performance while memory won't go above 150MB. Previously app was crashing at 1,3GB due to memory pressure.

```
let group = AsyncGroup()
var allPaths = [(Int, Int)]()

// Some logic to fill the paths -> not interesting

for path in allPaths {
    group.enter() // The following block will be added to the group
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        autoreleasepool { // Creating an autoreleasepool to free up memory for the loaded statistics

            // Stripped unnecessary stuff

            if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) {

                // Load the statistics from .dat files
                NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(_OldStatisticsDataModel.self, forClassName: "StatisticsDataModel")
                if let statistics = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? [_OldStatisticsDataModel] {

                    // Loop through days
                    for i in 1...31 {
                        autoreleasepool {
                            // Do the heavy stuff here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        group.leave() // Block has finished, now leave the group
    }
}

group.wait()
```